# Vertically and Horizontally Centered for Parallax site

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a parallax website, and am trying to have my content vertically and horizontally centered, but left align.

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B3nxK/37/

HTML:

```
    <div class="container box">    
        <div class="anchor" id="fit"></div>
        <div class="section fit red">
            <div class="t">
                <div class="tc">
                     <h1>Fit</h1>
                    <p>width and height</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section fit green">
            <div class="t">
                <div class="tc">
                     <h1>Fit</h1>
                    <p>width and height</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


Thanks in advance.


EDIT
--
```

Please see the code below for the bootstrap. The center column contains the main information. And each "section" is suppose to be individually centered to a full-page. It is suppose to be like a parallax scrolling site with the background not changing for each sections, but instead objects appear and goes away upon scrolling.

HTML:

```
            <div class="row vertical-align">

                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 left-col">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content">
                    <div id="menu" style="background-color:red">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="columnone" style="background-color:green">
                                <p class="categories">STARTERS</p>

                                <p class="names">BARRAMUNDI</p>
                                <p class="description">Atus alitatur magnatquos aut estiisc idebit, od quis volorporem. Se cus repelliquae mo consed mod ut adicabo ribusciam ipsumquas</p>
                                <p class="cost">-45</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="columntwo" style="background-color:blue">
                                <p class="categories">MAINS</p>

                                <p class="names">BARRAMUNDI</p>
                                <p class="description">Atus alitatur magnatquos aut estiisc idebit, od quis volorporem. Se cus repelliquae mo consed mod ut adicabo ribusciam ipsumquas</p>
                        <p class="cost">-45</p>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

        <div id="about" style="background-color:yellow">
            <p class="about_header">OUR RESTAURANT</p>
            <p class="about_info">Uptatio. Ulparumet fugitatibus, occusda cum fuga. Et esed quam ipid ut eum si am re desedis. Ommolum faciet imporep erepudae vel in el mil iliquo blautatur, aut officipis ium venis dolupta que possimo esti ut vellaut et restis adit latem sam, odit perum landit doles aute sanis estempos eos et que omni tetus ea peditatur.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 right-col">     
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body{
    background: url(../assets/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.row{
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Comment: _See stackover flow:_ what?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way...

You could move your content from "section" to a new "subsection",
then make "section" width 80% and add red/green/blue/etc to subsections (to re-add background color).

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra div like this:

```
<div class="tc">
   <div id="xyz">
     <h1>Fit</h1>
     <p>width and height</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#xyz {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B3nxK/44/)**

Comment: thanks for your solution. I see that it works in the js fiddle. However, I am using Twitter Bootstrap, and it does not seem to be working. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Share your bootstrap code and I'll try to figure out, what's going wrong in there.

Comment: Please see the edited text above. I've tried the suggested code in jsFiddle, but it did not work, so I took it. Let me know if you have any thoughts on it.  Thanks